# converting JSON to array

Tags: javascript, html, json, jquery

when executing url in my browser i have this:

```
   [{
       "id": "1234",
       "name": "Carl",
       "age": "17"
   }, {
       "id": "9876",
       "name": "Jhon",
       "age": "19"
   }]
```

i have this function:

```
     function get(callback) {
         return $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             // url: 'rest/cars/list',
             url: 'my url',
             dataType: "json",
             context: this,
             success: function (response) {
                 callback.call(this, response);
             }
         });
     };
```

my code is this:

```
  var pos = get();
  var ob = JSON.parse(pos);
  var arr = [];
  for (var i in ob) {
      if (ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          arr.push(ob[i]);
          alert(arr[i]);
      }
  }
```

i need to know how to convert the JSON into an array so i will have:

```
arr[0].id = 1234
```

etc...
my code is not working i have this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o ...
i am desperate to solve this issue

Comment: are you making a synchronous request?

Comment: i dont know i am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of calling the `get()` function is invalid. The `get()` method expects a callback function which is not supplied. Also the value returned from the `get()` function is a jQuery object. Not the response you are getting from the server. Please refer the following implementation.

Make the following change in the success function:

```
     function get(callback) {
         return $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             // url: 'rest/cars/list',
             url: 'my url',
             dataType: "json",
             context: this,
             success: function (response) {
                 callback(response);
             }
         });
     };
```

And call the get() method as follows:

```
get(function(pos){
var ob = pos;
  var arr = [];
  for (var i in ob) {
      if (ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          arr.push(ob[i]);
          alert(arr[i]);
      }
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thats not the prob i just changed the data when posting it here thaks anyway

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: Ok, the issue is with the way you are calling the get method. I have updated the answer. Please try this.

Comment: i get this now Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: line: var ob= JSON.parse(pos);

Comment: Try removing the JSON.parse(pos), since the object pos might be a JSON object already as we are specifying the dataType as JSON in the request.

Comment: yow bro i got this... :D :D :D :D  so in your code just put ob=pos the $.ajax alreadt makes the parsing thanks bro :)

Answer (score 0):

This JSON is invalid here:

```
  [{
      id: "1234",
      name: "Carl",
      age: "17", //this is invalid
  }, {
      id: "9876",
      name: 'Jhon',
      age: "19"
  }]
```

This is a valid version:

```
[{
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "Carl",
    "age": "17"
},
{
    "id": "9876",
    "name": "Jhon",
    "age": "19"
}]
```

You can validate here: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @user2702379: You already have an array of objects. So why you need to convert JSON into array. Did you want to convert an array into JSON?

Comment: no its good i am loading it in my PrimeUI data table, but i dont know how to fill my JSON file (that i cant change) in an array

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xXX38/)**

Try this code

```
  var obj=[{
       id: "1234",
       name: "Carl",
       age: "17",
   }, {
       id: "9876",
       name: 'Jhon',
       age: "19"
   }];

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    alert(obj[i]['age']);
    alert(obj[i]['id']);    
    alert(obj[i]['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json_data = your correct json data here
var result = [];

for(var i in json_data)
result.push([i, json_data [i]]);

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'ID');
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Age');
data.addRows(result);
```

Comment: i tried it but am getting ReferenceError: google is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's JSON parser is very strict, your JSON is not valid

all object keys needs to be in double quotes, and you can't mix and match single/double quotes like `'Jhon'`.

```
[   
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "Carl",
        "age": "17"
    },
    {
        "id": "9876",
        "name": "Jhon",
        "age": "19"
    }
]
```